# How to enter betaflight CLI mode by sending command directly to serial

Tags: javascript, serial-port, stm32

My goal is to enter betaflight CLI mode programmatically by sending some kind of command to serial

I tried to do something like that but it didn't help me
[snippet from betaflight configurator app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfwoG.png)
Also i tried to directly send `UInt8Array([0x23])`, but again it didn't help me.